# Storing Biometric Data on MIFARE Cards for Two-Factor Authentication

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics, mifare

I have database of fingerprints stored in WSQ format and I am trying to use a Two-Factor authentication by verifying that the biometric data stored on the card matches the finger being placed on the scanner (which in turn is linked to a database of registered fingerprints).

My challenge is, to use the card reader, the templates must be stored as a VUR,BUR or TEM file. Does anyone know how I can convert WSQ files to any of these formats for onward storage on the MIFARE cards? BTW The device/reader is an L-1 4G V-FLEX LITE(4GFXLSO) reader